# Address VMWare Fusion Linux guest by hostname?

Tags: linux, macos, vmware-fusion, ubuntu-9.04, hostname

I have a Ubuntu Server 9.04 image set up in VMWare Fusion 3.0.0, using the NAT option for the guest's network connection.  From the Mac host, I can ssh to the linux guest just fine using it's IP address, but I would like to be able to refer to it by hostname for convenience.  ie:

```
mac-host:~ ssh user@linux-guest.local
```

I had a similar setup using Parallels a couple years ago, but I don't remember how it was set up.  It may have "just worked".

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT** The first version of instructions I posted caused conflicts with the nameserver and gateway that VMware put on vmnet8. This version corrects the issue.

Software versions:

- MAC OS X Version 10.6.3
- VMware Fusion Version 3.1.0 (261058)
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

What I have done:

- During creation of the VM, set
  networking to NAT.
- **On Linux Guest:** Run ifconfig to get the hardware address `HWaddr`, broadcast address `Bcast`, IPv4 internet address `inet addr`, and mask `Mask` being used.

  ```
  UbuntuGuest$ifconfig
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:53:bf:e5  
            inet addr:192.168.213.129  Bcast:192.168.213.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                   <snip>
  ```
- **On Linux Guest:** Lookup the nameserver information

  ```
  UbuntuGuest$cat /etc/resolv.conf
  nameserver 192.168.213.2
  domain localdomain
  search localdomain
  ```
- **On Linux Guest:** Lookup the gateway address: (Listed in the Gateway column of the line with 0.0.0.0 as Destination.)

  ```
  UbuntuGuest$route -n
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  192.168.213.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
  0.0.0.0         192.168.213.2   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
  ```
- **On OS X Host:** Edit the `dhcpd.conf` file for `vmnet8` (The NAT virtual switch) to assign a static IP address to the Linux Guest. (Use your editor of choice on the fourth line)

  ```
  OSXHost$cd /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet8/
  OSXHost$sudo chmod u+w dhcpd.conf
  OSXHost$sudo cp dhcpd.conf dhcpd.conf.bak.20100619
  OSXHost$sudo emacs dhcpd.conf
  ```
- **On OS X Host:** The file will start out looking something like:

  ```
  # Configuration file for ISC 2.0 vmnet-dhcpd operating on vmnet8.
  #
  # This file was automatically generated by the VMware configuration program.
  # See Instructions below if you want to modify it.
  #
  # We set domain-name-servers to make some DHCP clients happy
  # (dhclient as configured in SuSE, TurboLinux, etc.).
  # We also supply a domain name to make pump (Red Hat 6.x) happy.
  #


  ###### VMNET DHCP Configuration. Start of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #####
  # Modification Instructions: This section of the configuration file contains
  # information generated by the configuration program. Do not modify this
  # section.
  # You are free to modify everything else. Also, this section must start
  # on a new line
  # This file will get backed up with a different name in the same directory
  # if this section is edited and you try to configure DHCP again.

  # Written at: 12/26/2009 10:35:10
  allow unknown-clients;
  default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes
  max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours

  subnet 192.168.213.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.213.128 192.168.213.254;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.213.255;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.213.2;
        option domain-name localdomain;
        default-lease-time 1800;         # default is 30 minutes
        max-lease-time 7200;             # default is 2 hours
    option routers 192.168.213.2;
  }
  host vmnet8 {
      hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:08;
      fixed-address 192.168.213.1;
      option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
      option domain-name "";
      option routers 0.0.0.0;
  }
  ####### VMNET DHCP Configuration. End of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #######
  ```

---

Things to note:

- The `subnet` section should match the IP information gathered on the Linux Guest. The `inet addr` will be within `range`, `netmask` will match `Mask`, `option broadcast-address` will match `Bcast`, `option domain-name-servers` and `option domain-name` will match the information gathered with `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `option routers` will match `Gateway` from the `route -n` command.
- We want to assign a static IP address, so that we can add an entry to the OS X Host's `hosts` file. The address must be within the `subnet` defined.  Addresses that are not available to assign are the ones within `range` in subnet section, the broadcast address, the `fixed-address` for `host vmnet8`, the DNS server and the gateway. And I think the address equal to subnet is not allowed. In this example, the subnet is `192.168.213.0` So the available addressees are from `192.168.213.1 to 192.168.213.255` less `192.168.213.128 to 192.168.213.245` (range) less `192.168.213.255` (broadcast) less `192.168.213.1` (host vmnet8) less `192.168.213.2` (gateway and DNS server). The net is that addresses `192.168.213.3 to 192.168.213.127` are available.

---

- **ON OS X Host:** Create a new `host` entry below the  *DO NOT MODIFY SECTION*. This entry will assign a static IP to the Linux Guest. `hardware ethernet` needs to match `HWaddr` from `ifconfig` on the Linux Guest. Pick an available static address for `fixed-address`. `option broadcast-address`, `option domain-name-servers`, `option domain-name` and `option routers` need to match the options given in the `subnet` section of `dhcpd.conf`. (Which we have already matched against information gathered on the Linux Guest.) In this example the host entry is:

  ```
  ####### VMNET DHCP Configuration. End of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #######
  host serpents-hold {
      hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:53:bf:e5;
      fixed-address 192.168.213.3;
      option broadcast-address 192.168.213.255;
      option domain-name-servers 192.168.213.2;
      option domain-name localdomain;
      option routers 192.168.213.2;
  }
  ```
- **On OS X Host** Save `dhcpd.conf` and close your editor.
- **On OS X Host and all Guests:** Shutdown all VMs and VMware.
- **On OS X Host:** Restart the VMware services:

  ```
  OSXHost$cd /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/ 
  OSXHost$sudo ./boot.sh --restart
  ```
- **On OS X Host:** Look in `Activity Monitor` and make sure that two processes each named `vmnet-dhcpd` are running. (One is for the `vmnet8`, the NAT network, the other is for the host only network.) If you don't see both, there is probably a problem with the `vmnet8/dhcpd.conf` file on the OS X Host. Fix that and repeat the restart of VMware services.
- **On OS X Host:** Start VMware and the Linux Guest VM.
- **On Linux Guest** On the guest VM check that settings are as expected:

  ```
  UbuntuGuest$ifconfig
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:53:bf:e5  
            inet addr:192.168.213.3  Bcast:192.168.213.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe53:bfe5/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:10961 (10.9 KB)  TX bytes:9637 (9.6 KB)
  lo <snip>    
  UbuntuGuest$cat /etc/resolv.conf
  nameserver 192.168.213.2
  domain localdomain
  search localdomain
  UbuntuGuest$route -n
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  192.168.213.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
  0.0.0.0         192.168.213.2   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
  UbuntuGuest$
  ```
- **On Linux Guest:** Check that the outside world is reachable:

  ```
  UbuntuGuest$ping google.com
  PING google.com (72.14.213.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from pv-in-f104.1e100.net (72.14.213.104): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=47.6 ms
  64 bytes from 2.bp.blogspot.com (72.14.213.104): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=48.7 ms
  64 bytes from 2.bp.blogspot.com (72.14.213.104): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=48.2 ms
  ^C
  --- google.com ping statistics ---
  4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 3093ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.687/48.223/48.714/0.491 ms
  UbuntuGuest$
  ```
- **On OS X Host:** Add a mapping for the hostname to the `hosts` file:

  ```
  OSXHost$cd /etc
  OSXHost$sudo emacs hosts
  ```

  Add a line to the end of the hosts file using the Linux Guest's hostname and the IP address assigned above.

  ```
  192.168.213.2   serpents-hold
  ```
- **On OS X Host:** Save file and exit emacs.
- **On OS X Host:** Test that the Linux Guest is reachable by hostname:

  ```
  OSXHost$ping serpents-hold
  PING serpents-hold (192.168.213.3): 56 data bytes
  64 bytes from 192.168.213.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.169 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.213.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
  ^C
  --- serpents-hold ping statistics ---
  2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
  round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.169/0.207/0.244/0.037 ms
  OSXHost$
  ```

Comment: This is great...if your on an OSX host.  Wish I could find the windows equivalent somewhere.

Comment: Great info. Thanks. 2 updates for v4.x

1. Location of dhcpd.conf is now: "/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/"

2. In Fusion 4, the networking service does not run when Fusion is shut down. To restart the networking service, restart Fusion.

Answer (score 10):

The one step answer to the original question is to run this command:

> $ sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns

Installing this package should enable the feature instantly. You will then be able to get to your VM at `your-vm-hostname.local`. This will only work within the local network of the VM, which depends on how you configured it in your virtualization software.

This feature is called Bonjour by Apple and Zeroconf by everyone else. It's built into OS X and iOS. The easiest way to get it on Windows is to install iTunes for Windows.

Comment: Using this, I need to append '.local' to the name of the guest machine, e.g. `ubuntu-guest.local`, when I refer to it from the host side.  That aside, this works wonderfully!

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot That's true. That's what the original poster wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You could configure zeroconf using Avahi, which should allow the client to identify itself on a network without DNS registration.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you just want to login over a command line, why not create an [ssh config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) file? i do something like this for my vm.

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host linux-box    
Hostname localhost
Port 8822
```

then i can

```
mac-box:~ ssh linux-box
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NAT, it may try to register with DNS servers, however to computers other than the host, it's IP will be the same as your machines and can cause a few problems.

I would recommend that you switch to bridged networking as this will give it its own IP address and to any machine, it will look and feel like any other machine on the network. If you set up all the IP settings correctly (or use DHCP), it should automatically register and you should not have a problem doing anything on any port via IP or hostname.

Comment: Yes I think that would work but I'd prefer a stable private network.  The VM is on a laptop that moves around and sometimes doesn't have an internet connection.  If I used bridged-mode, I wouldn't be able to contact it when the host was offline.