# How can I access a VMware Fusion guest running Ubuntu via its .local (Bonjour/Zeroconf/mdns) address?

Tags: linux, vmware-fusion, hostname, zeroconf, avahi

I'm running VMware Fusion on my Mac with an Ubuntu guest VM configured to use NAT for networking. I can access the VM from the host using its DHCP-assigned vmnet8 IP (172.16.90.128), but I'd like to be able to access it as ubuntu.local as well, e.g.:

```
mac:~$ ssh ubuntu.local
```

I am running the avahi daemon in the guest VM but it doesn't seem to be reaching the Mac.

I found [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/72199/address-vmware-fusion-linux-guest-by-hostname), but none of the answers really addressed the issue; I don't want to configure the host's DHCP server or ssh config.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding a line like

```
172.16.90.128   ubuntu.local
```

to your /etc/hosts file: